# jQuery trying to get value of <strong> tag

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to get the value of the strong tag inside the echo with jQuery. I have 3 rows in the database so there are 3 results. Every result has it's own productname. Lets say row 1 = Salad, row 2 = baguette, row 3 = tunasalad. If i press on button: "addToCart" i want to add tunasalad to an array. How can i do this? I've tried this:

```
while($gerechten = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  echo '
    <div class="well"> <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <strong class="productname" style="font-size: 17px;">' . $gerechten['productname'] . '</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addToCart" name="add" id="addToCart" style="margin-top: -3px;">€'.$gerechten['price_medium'].',00  <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>';
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var i = [];

$( document ).ready(function() {        
  $('.addToCart').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(e) {        
      i.push($('.productname').text());
      console.log(i);
    }); 
  });
});
```

OUTPUT IN CONSOLE:

```
["SaladBaguetteTunasalad"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on each of the `.addToCart` classes, you're calling `i.push($('.productname').text());`. This will add **every** element with the class `productName` to `i`.

Instead, what you want to do is make use of `this`, **[`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** and **[`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** to only add the elements with the class `productName` which are the relevant items for `.addToCart`.

Note that you can't simply use `siblings()`, and need to call `.parent()` **twice** so that you target `.col-lg-12`, as the two elements are also separated by the `pull` classes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.addToCart').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(e) {
      i.push($(this).parent().parent().find('.productname').text());
      console.log(i);
    });
  });
});
```

Depending on your HTML structure, you might actually find that making use of **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** with `i.push($(this).closest('.row').find('.productname').text());` works more consistently for you. It's also shorter, which is always nice :)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for that! Can you maybe tell me how i can output this array to my view?

Comment: `i.push($(this).closest('.row').find('.productname').text());` might be a shorter and less structure-dependent version.

Comment: ^ Also great; will swap that out :)

Comment: @itvba -- You have the array saved as `i`, it simply depends on how you want to make use of it. You could opt for setting an `innerHTML` if you so desire.

Comment: I just want to add the array to my shopping cart :)

Comment: Well it depends on exactly what your shopping cart comprises of. If it's in JavaScript, simply use `document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = i[0]`. If it's in PHP, you'll probably want to grab the ID associated to the product and make a `$_POST` request out to another file.

Comment: Remember `i` is an array.

Comment: Yep. You're looking for `i[0]` to access the first index of that array :) Alternatively, you could always loop over it and output everything stored in the array.

Comment: Instead of `.each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(e)`, why not go `on('click', function()`?